# hadoop fs -mkdir failed on connection exception

Tags: hadoop

I have been trying to set up and run Hadoop in the pseudo Distributed Mode.But when I type

> bin/hadoop fs -mkdir input

I get

> mkdir: Call From h1/192.168.1.13 to h1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

here is the details

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/home/grid/tmp</value>
  </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://h1:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
        <value>h1:9001</value>
    </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
    <value>20</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
    <value>4</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address</name>
    <value>h1:50030</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
    <value>h1:10020</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
    <value>h1:19888</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.http.address</name>
    <value>h1:50070</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address</name>
    <value>h1:9001</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
    <value>h1:50090</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/home/grid/data</value>
  </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.1.13 h1
192.168.1.14 h2
192.168.1.15 h3
```

After hadoop namenode -format and start-all.sh

```
1702 ResourceManager
1374 DataNode
1802 NodeManager
2331 Jps
1276 NameNode
1558 SecondaryNameNode
```

the problem occurs

```
[grid@h1 hadoop-2.6.0]$ bin/hadoop fs -mkdir input
15/05/13 16:37:57 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: Call From h1/192.168.1.13 to h1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Where is the problems?

hadoop-grid-datanode-h1.log

```
2015-05-12 11:26:20,329 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = h1/192.168.1.13
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.6.0
```

hadoop-grid-namenode-h1.log

```
2015-05-08 16:06:32,561 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = h1/192.168.1.13
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.6.0
```

why the port 9000 does not work?

```
[grid@h1 ~]$ netstat -tnl |grep 9000
[grid@h1 ~]$ netstat -tnl |grep 9001
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.13:9001           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

Comment: Post your namenode and datanode logs.

Comment: Are both of your machines 32 bit OS?

Comment: Is your HDFS instance is running on the specified port "9000" ?

Comment: wow, it seems that the port "9000" does not open, but I still cannot figure out why, the port 9001 can work

Answer (score 2):

Please start dfs and yarn.

[hadoop@hadooplab sbin]$ **./start-dfs.sh**

[hadoop@hadooplab sbin]$ **./start-yarn.sh**

Now try using "*bin/hadoop fs -mkdir input*"

The issue usually comes when you install hadoop in a VM and then shut it down. When you shut down VM, dfs and yarn also stops. So you need to start dfs and yarn each time you restart the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try command

```
bin/hadoop dfs -mkdir input
```

If you have followed micheal-roll post properly then you should not have any issue. I suspect that passwordless ssh is not working in your configuration, recheck it.

Comment: [grid@h1 hadoop-2.6.0]$ bin/hadoop dfs -mkdir input
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

15/05/14 09:45:27 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: Call From h1/192.168.1.13 to h1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Comment: so did you figure out why port 9000 is not opening? try restarting the system once.

Answer (score 0):

Following procedure resolved the issue for me:

1. Stop all the services.
2. Delete namenode and datanode directories as specified in hdfs-site.xml.
3. Create new namenode and datanode directories and modify hdfs-site.xml accordingly.
4. In core-site.xml, make the following changes or add the following properties:

   fs.defaultFS
     hdfs://172.20.12.168/


     fs.default.name
     hdfs://172.20.12.168:8020
5. Make the following changes in hadoop-2.6.4/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh file:

   export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
6. Restart dfs, yarn and mr as follows:

   start-dfs.sh
    start-yarn.sh
    mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me:

```
hadoop namenode -format
```