# hadoop error: util.NativeCodeLoader (hdfs dfs -ls does not work!)

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have seen a lot of folks getting problem with hadoop installation. I went through all the related stackoverflow questions, but could not fix the problem.

The problem is :

```
hdfs dfs -ls 
16/09/27 09:43:42 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: `.': No such file or directory
```

1. I am using ubuntu 16.04 and I downloaded hadoop stable version 2.7.2 from Apache mirror:
   http://apache.spinellicreations.com/hadoop/common/
2. I have installed java and ssh already.

   which java
   java is /usr/bin/java
   which javac
   javac is /usr/bin/javac
   which ssh
   ssh is /usr/bin/ssh
   echo $JAVA_HOME
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64

Note:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1091      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1091      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

3. hadoop environment variables in ~/.bashrc

   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64
   export HADOOP_INSTALL=/home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2
   export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
   export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
   export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
   export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
   export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
   export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
   export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
   export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
   export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
4. Modification of file:
   `/home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`

Added a one line at the end:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64
```

The link to hadoop-env.sh in the pastebin is here:
http://pastebin.com/a3iPjB04

5. Then I created some empty directories:

   /home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2/tmp
   /home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/hadoop_store
   /home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/hadoop_store/hdfs
   /home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2etc/hadoop/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode
   /home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode
6. Modifications to the file: `/home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml`

> ```
> <property>  
>   <name>dfs.replication</name>  
>   <value>1</value>  
>   <description>Default block replication.  
>   The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.  
>   The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.  
>   </description>  
>  </property>  
>  <property>  
>    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>  
>   <value>file:/home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
>
>  </property>  
>  <property>  
>    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>  
>    <value>file:/home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
>
>  </property>
> ```

The link in the pastebin is this:
http://pastebin.com/cha7ZBr8

7. Modifications to the file: `/home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml`

is following:

> hadoop.tmp.dir
>   /home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2/tmp   A base
>   for other temporary directories.
>
> fs.default.name
>   hdfs://localhost:54310   The name of the
>   default file system.  A URI whose   scheme and authority determine the
>   FileSystem implementation.  The   uri's scheme determines the config
>   property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming   the FileSystem implementation
>   class.  The uri's authority is used to   determine the host, port,
>   etc. for a filesystem.

The link to the pastebin for core-site.xml is this: 
 http://pastebin.com/D184DuGB

8. The Modification to file are given below: `/home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml`

> mapred.job.tracker
>   localhost:54311   The host and port that
>   the MapReduce job tracker runs   at.  If "local", then jobs are run
>   in-process as a single map   and reduce task.

The pastebin link is:
http://pastebin.com/nVxs8nMm

9. when I type hostname in the terminal it says BP

   cat /etc/hosts
   127.0.0.1   localhost BP
   127.0.1.1   localhost

   ## The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

   ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
   fe00::0 ip6-localnet
   ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
   ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
   ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
10. I have also disabled ipv6

    cat /etc/sysctl.conf
    net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
    net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
    net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
11. hadoop descriptions

    hadoop version
    Hadoop 2.7.2

    which hadoop
    hadoop is /home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hadoop

    which hdfs
    hdfs is /home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hdfs
12. Restarting hadoop

    cd /home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin
    stop-dfs.sh
    stop-yarn.sh

    cd /home/bhishan/hadoop-2.7.2/tmp && rm -Rf *
    hadoop namenode -format

    start-dfs.sh
    start-yarn.sh
13. Now the error comes

> hdfs dfs -ls
>
> 16/09/26 23:53:14 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load
>   native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>   where applicable ls: `.': No such file or directory

14. checking jps

    jps
    6688 sun.tools.jps.Jps
    3909 SecondaryNameNode
    3525 NameNode
    4327 NodeManager
    4184 ResourceManager
    3662 DataNode
15. checknative

    hadoop checknative -a
    16/09/27 09:28:18 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    Native library checking:
    hadoop:  false
    zlib:    false
    snappy:  false
    lz4:     false
    bzip2:   false
    openssl: false
    16/09/27 09:28:18 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
16. Then I installed missing libraries:
    a) which hadoop gives Hadoop 2.7.2

b) sudo apt-get install --reinstall zlibc zlib1g zlib1g-dev
From synaptic manager I can see following libraries installed:
  zlib1g, zlib1g-dev , zlib1g:i386, zlibc

c) Installed snappy and python-snappy.

d) In Synaptic manager I can see lz4
liblz4-1, liblz4-tool, python-lz4, python3-lz4

e) bzip2 is already installed.

f) openssl is already installed.

17. All checknative are false and I can not run hdfs dfs -ls
    I could not find any errors till now. Any help will be appreciated.

Also, I am trying to run hadoop in Single laptop with four cores. The version is 2.7.2, How is version 3.0, If I have to reinstall the hadoop from Scratch, may be I should go with hadoop3. Suggestions will be welcomed.

Related links:
[Result of hdfs dfs -ls command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381103/result-of-hdfs-dfs-ls-command)
[hdfs dfs ls not working after multiple nodes configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907249/hdfs-dfs-ls-not-working-after-multiple-nodes-configured)
[hadoop fs -ls does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351511/hadoop-fs-ls-does-not-work)
[Namenode not getting started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076439/namenode-not-getting-started)
[No Namenode or Datanode or Secondary NameNode to stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772495/no-namenode-or-datanode-or-secondary-namenode-to-stop)
[Hadoop 2.6.1 Warning: WARN util.NativeCodeLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800018/hadoop-2-6-1-warning-warn-util-nativecodeloader)
[Hadoop 2.2.0 Setup (Pseudo-Distributed Mode): ERROR// Warn util.NativeCodeLoader: unable to load native-hadoop library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144371/hadoop-2-2-0-setup-pseudo-distributed-mode-error-warn-util-nativecodeloader)
[Command "hadoop fs -ls ." does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201731/command-hadoop-fs-ls-does-not-work)

And, also,
[hadoop fs -mkdir failed on connection exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210893/hadoop-fs-mkdir-failed-on-connection-exception)
[Hadoop cluster setup - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661285/hadoop-cluster-setup-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused)
[Hadoop (local and host destination do not match) after installing hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161078/hadoop-local-and-host-destination-do-not-match-after-installing-hive/20169445#20169445)

Help will be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this error:

```
hdfs dfs -ls 
16/09/27 09:43:42 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: `.': No such file or directory
```

Ignore the warning about the native libraries - the command should work fine even with that warning.

When you run hdfs dfs -ls with no path as you have done, it attempts to list the contents of your home directory in HDFS, which is /user/ by default. In this case, I suspect this issue is simply that your user directory does not exist.

Does it work OK if you run:

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

And then do:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/<your_user_name>
hadoop fs -ls
```

Comment: If you run "hdfs dfs -mkdir /user", does that give an error or work?

Comment: Oh wait!, now I again restarted hadoop, now hadoop fs -ls /    WORKS!

Comment: But: hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/bhishan    FAILS!  sudo mkdir -p /user/bhishan works.

Comment: AGAIN: hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/bhishan/junk_sep27 FAILS!

Comment: what error does "hdfs dfs mkdir -p /user/bhishan" give? 

If you only want to play around with Hadoop, the easiest path is to download a quick start VM from Cloudera.com - it is all setup and working which lets you concentrate on learning Hadoop and avoids these install type issues.